# wp_print_scripts runs twice

Tags: scripts

I am currently using a child theme of the Hueman theme.

I am filtering the different JS scripts, page by page.

So, I use the following function, in order to display which scripts are used:

```
// Finding handle for your plugins
function display_script_handles() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $id=0;
    if(current_user_can('manage_options') && ! is_admin()){ # Only load when user is admin
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
         $obj = $wp_scripts->registered [$handle];
         echo $filename = $obj->src;
         echo ' : <b>Handle for this script is:</b> <span style="color:green"> '.$handle.'</span><br/><br/>';
         $id++;
    endforeach;
    }
    echo '<p style="color:red;font-weight:600;font-size:2em;">Nombre de scripts : '.$id.'</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'display_script_handles' );
```

Then, I load the homepage in order for me to see these handles.
However, I can see that wp_print_scripts runs twice.

Is that an issue ? Does it mean that each script is loaded twice ?

Besides, each time it runs, it displays a different number of scripts. Maybe there's a reason for it ?

Thank you for your help.